# How to insert horizontal line to page headers in Apple Pages

Tags: pages

I need to include a horizontal line beneath the text of the header in each page of my document. I was able to add a line using the Shape tool, but I cannot get it to repeat when enough text is added to create additional pages.

Can someone tell me how to accomplish this? Here's a screenshot of how I'd like the top of each page to look: (obviously the page number would be different)

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Insert a line, move it on the page into the header box (this is easier if you have layout visible - VIEW / SHOW LAYOUT)

Make the line a section master (ARRANGE / SECTION MASTER / MOVE OBJECT TO SECTION MASTER)

Answer (score 5):

I did the following:

```
 1) Click anywhere on paragraph section (not the header section)

 2) Go to Format on sidebar and select Layout tab

 3) Expand Borders & Rules (click upside down triangle)

 4) Select Solid Line from dropdown list

 5) Select desired Position (above paragraph)

 6) adjust the offset distance from top of paragraph if u wish
    adjust thickness if u wish
```